# Is it better to use Android's built-in frame-by-frame animation methods or create your own?

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics

I have downloaded several example Android games, and most of them do not use Android's animation methods. I have also seen several posts on this site and other sites where some say that they prefer not to use Android's animation methods, but they never explain *why*.

**So, is it generally better not to use Android's animations for games?**

Comment: What are the criteria for your game?

Comment: Let's take something simple for example - a game where multiple objects spawn on the screen then move in a certain direction until you tap them. Most of the examples I've seen are something similar. It would seem that Android's animation methods would be simpler for such a game, but none of the examples I've seen use them.

Comment: when you say that the games aren't using Android's animation methods, exactly what do you mean? How exactly do these developers move objects in their games without using them? Android has a lot of ways to animate objects.  I'd be real surprised if none of them were used.

Comment: @Martin Changing an object's X and Y values on a loop doesn't implement any animation methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using Android's Animation classes for games. The reason is that they operate on Views which are not lightweight enough for the high performance games require. Views are designed for buttons, text, and images that mostly stay still, *positioned in organized layouts*, and not for images that move all over the place. The two best approaches for making games with Android are:

- Using the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) class. Note that this will only work for simple 2-D sprite-based games, as it tends to be quite slow. It's relatively easy for beginners to learn.
- Using [OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). This works for pretty much any game - it's fast and can do both 2-D and 3-D games. **Be warned,** it is very complicated and I would not recommend beginners use OpenGL ES!

If you are new to programming games, I would recommend buying a book on the topic such as Mario Zechner's excellent book "Beginning Android Games" (look for it on Amazon). This book starts by making a "Snake" clone using Canvas, then walks through the basics of OpenGL and shows you how to make a 2-D "Doodle Jump"-like game, then transitions into 3-D by making a 3-D "Space Invaders" app. I highly recommend this book, it explains everything really clearly, is not a boring read, and is what I used to make my first game on Android.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

There is a third option for making games for Android: using a pre-built game library. These libraries provide the advantage of speed by being based OpenGL but are much easier to use. Many are also cross-platform, meaning your code will be easier to port to other operating systems such as iOS. (Keep in mind that cross-platform solutions are not always ideal, though.) Examples of game free libraries include [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) and [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com). If you do choose to go down this path, make sure to follow the licence agreement (this may involve putting some sort of logo on the main screen).

These libraries are good and provide an easy entry into game development, but keep in mind that creating a game from scratch will provide knowledge and a sense of accomplishment you  won't get anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! I wish you success with your game.